# symfony, where should I store path to the folder, to be able to access it from anywhere?

Tags: symfony, configuration, constants

I am writing an app where people can upload files. Where should I store the path to that folder(folder for files users upload) to be able to access it from anywhere in the code, instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: If your'e using Symfony < 3.4, in the `parameters.yml` file. From 3.4, put it in an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

If your'e using Symfony < 3.4 you could add this to your `parameters.yml` config file

```
web_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
```

which would be the standard path to the public accessible web folder in your app. You could inject this parameter into a service that moves your uploads or retrieve the parameter in a Controller